# Will Bhattacharyya distance always increase when increasing the number of features used to describe two populations of images?

Tags: image-processing, feature-selection

I have 3 classes of images of human cells.  I have extracted 600+ features from the images and can separate the classes quite well using several features selected using a random forest machine learning algorithm.  When I measure the Bhattacharyya distance between each class I notice if I add more features that the Bhattacharyya distance gets larger (as long as I don't add a duplicate feature).  I will surely have new classes of cells to look at in the future so it is tempting to add in as many features as possible to increase the separation of the present classes and to enable the separation of future unknown classes.  Am I fooling myself in thinking I am better able to delineate one cell type from another  by adding more features and getting larger Bhattacharyya distance between them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is specific to the distance measure but more towards feature selection. I think in general the more independent features you add the more separation you will get. But it will also likely decrease the within group variance perhaps even to the point of separating a group of similar objects creating an over constrained problem.

In classification there is always the possibility of creating an overly constrained feature set. So your classifier may work perfectly on the training data, but fails in the real world because in adding more features (constraints) you made the classifier too selective. Just think how we as humans determine if something is different. like with this image.

[image: http://tx.english-ch.com/teacher/ackie/spot-the-difference-christmas-1.jpg]

using color alone as a classifier we find 2 differences (Star vs red ribbon, on presents orange vs red ribbon). so we further constrain our problem and use size and we find the red ball. adding a shape constraint we find the red diamond vs crescent, and the two different snowflakes.

You can see that any one of these classifiers would have adequately separated the two images, but combined together we have a very strong line between the two images, but it isn't very robust/flexible. What if we clone the image on the left and make the yellow ball red? With our highly constrained groups, we'd have to assume it belongs to a new group. But if we only classified using our shape classifier, we'd still have two groups. Group one has a bows  on the top of the trees and group 2 has stars. Which case did you want? It is all application specific. But generally less features may mean a classifier that isn't selective (large variance within group/under constrained) and as you add more features your classifier may become too selective and in worse case treat every example as its own class (over constrained)